# Understanding the "elements" of this set

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis

Suppose $f\in C^3(M)$ where $M \subset \mathbb R^3$ is a $2$-dimensional manifold. For some $s>0$ and $\epsilon>0$ sufficiently small, we define

$A:=\bigg \{x_0+t\frac{\nabla f(x_0)}{|\nabla f(x_0)|}\;,\;0\leq t \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}\;,\;x_0\in\{f=s\} \bigg \}$

I want to understand what exactly $A$ contains. Intuitively, I realize $A$ as follows:

- $+\frac{\nabla f(x_0)}{|\nabla f(x_0)|}$ is the unit normal vector in $x_0 \in \{f=s\}$ pointing to the set $\{f>s \}$
- $x_0$ is some point of the level set $\{f=s \}$

Therefore, I imagine that as we "walk" through $t\frac{\nabla f(x_0)}{|\nabla f(x_0)|}$, the set $A$ includes all level sets starting from $\{f=s\}$ up to distance $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ from it. **Is this correct or am I missing something here?**

I would appreciate if somebody could enlighten me here! Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you know about $g$?

Comment: @Vajra Ooopss! I am sorry, it was a typo. I edited the post. Thanks!

Comment: So this is calling for the gradient computed *on* the surface $M$? Even if so, the vector addition moves you off $M$ and into $\Bbb R^3$ in general.

Comment: @TedShifrin I am sorry but I didn't get what you're saying. What do you mean by "off $M$?

Comment: If you have a curved surface $M$, start at a point $x_0$, and add tangent vectors to $M$ at $x_0$, the addition takes you away from the surface and into $\Bbb R^3-M$. Draw pictures. So what's written here will have nothing to do with level sets of $f$ in $M$. If $M$ is itself a level surface of a function $f$ defined on $\Bbb R^3$, then what you're saying makes more sense.